# Creating a large list of variables and keys with Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a semi-complex flashcard app and I have most all of it working except now I need to persist data to save scores and dates for review.  I have been reading into Core Data for about a day or so now and cannot find any information that (I think) could relate to what I am trying to do.

During testing, I created a class with properties for other objects(words) to inherit.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Flashcards: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var word:String = ""
@NSManaged var translation:String = ""
@NSManaged var sentence1:String = ""
@NSManaged var sentence2:String = ""
@NSManaged var sentence1Audio = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testAudio", ofType: "m4a")!)
// etc;
}
```

---

Then here I created around 10 or so flashcards with all the variables I need for the different kinds of testing.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

func setupWordBank() -> [Flashcards] {

// Declare all flashcards and properties.
@NSManaged var you = Flashcards()
you.word = "คุณ"
you.translation = "you"
you.sentence1 = "You like pie?"
you.sentence2 = "Your butt stinks!"
you.id = 0
you.score = 0
// etc;
}
```

The problem now, is how do I create a large list (up to 2000) words with 10 or so different properties that I can persist and change 1-2 properties at the end of a test?

I've tried creating entities in core data with identical attributes, but I do not know how to make a list defining and creating each card(word).  Is there another way to do this that would be more efficient and possibly easier on memory/mobile hard drive space?

Comment: So the question is how to get your items out of core data?

Comment: Currently I am not using core data, because I do not know how to set up the words in Core Data.  I can create the entity and attributes, but I have no way of declaring 500 words and setting values for all of the attributes.

Comment: Well, you need to import the data from somewhere. Where is it currently, just in code?

Comment: Yes, in it's own class.

Comment: Rewrite that code to create managed object instances

Comment: I just edited the variable code.  Is this what you mean?